# 日本語に違和感: ユーザー情報編集画面の「場所」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

「場所」だと何の場所を入力してよいのか迷いました。「居場所」とするのはどうでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 5):

> 現在地

Answer (score 2):

「居場所」はちょっと口語的で違和感があります。
「居住地」はいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 最初は住所を入力する箇所かと思ったので「居住地」と思ったのですが、英語版ではもっと広い意味で使われてると聞いて迷いました。所属しているチーム名を書いたりなど

Comment: なるほどそうでしたか。Locationは必ずしも地名とは限らないというニュアンスも含むのか、英語ネイティブではない私にはよくわかりませんが、そこまで完全に訳そうとすると難しいですね。まあ完璧な訳を目指す必要があるわけじゃない気もするので、日本版SOコミュニティの納得いく形に落ち着けばいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ほかの提案・意見がなかったら、「居場所」に変換させていただきます。

英語では「Location」ですので、いる場所（居場所）を示しています。ほかのサイトはどの使い方をしているかが知りませんので、居場所に違和感あったら、ご教示ください。

Comment: 少しやわらかい言葉だと「住んでいるところ」とかもありますね。

Comment: 別の案を足しました: 「現在地」